# RxJS how to grab first values that is not null from two promises

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to wrap my head around how RxJS concat works, and how it works with Promises in general.

I have two observables:

`currentConfirmation$` emits null

`newConfirmation$` emits a new confirmation

Could someone explain why this works:

```js
const finalConfirmation$ = currentConfirmation$.pipe(
    switchMap((conf) => {
      if (!conf) {
        return newConfirmation$
      }

      return of(conf)
    })
  )
```

But this does not

```js
const finalConfirmation$ = concat(currentConfirmation$, newConfirmation$).pipe(find((conf) => !!conf))
```

By not works I mean this test passes with the `switchMap` version and times out with the `concat` version

```js
test("updateConfirmation should create the confirmation if it doesn't exist", (done) => {
    updateConfirmation({ value: true, symbol: 'LTCUSD', name: 'LTC_TEST_CONFIRMATION_999' }).subscribe((conf) => {
      expect(conf.entityData).toEqual({ value: true, symbol: 'LTCUSD', name: 'LTC_TEST_CONFIRMATION_999' })
      done()
    })
  })
```

I would also love to know if there is a better approach to accomplishing the above than what I have come up with.

**Edit:**
Here is all the relevant code for the test:

```js
export const confirmationRepository$ = client$.pipe(
  switchMap(async (client) => client.fetchRepository(schema)),
  delayWhen((cr) => from(cr.createIndex())),
  shareReplay(1)
)

export const updateConfirmation = (newData: Partial<Confirmation>) => {
  // TODO: Just don't process the search if we get empty strings
  const currentConfirmation$ = getConfirmation(newData.symbol || ' ', newData.name || ' ')
  const newConfirmation$ = createConfirmation(newData)

  // const finalConfirmation$ = concat(currentConfirmation$, newConfirmation$).pipe(find((conf) => !!conf))
  const finalConfirmation$ = currentConfirmation$.pipe(
    switchMap(async (conf) => {
      if (!conf) {
        return newConfirmation$
      }
      return of(conf)
    }),
    concatAll(),
    combineLatestWith(confirmationRepository$),
    concatMap(async ([conf, confRepo]) => {
      conf.value = !!newData.value
      await confRepo.save(conf)
      return conf
    })
  )

  return finalConfirmation$
}

export const getConfirmation = (symbol: string, name: string) => {
  return confirmationRepository$.pipe(
    switchMap((cr) => cr.search().where('symbol').equals(symbol).and('name').equals(name).first())
  )
}

export const getConfirmations = (symbol: string) => {
  return confirmationRepository$.pipe(switchMap((cr) => cr.search().where('symbol').equals(symbol).returnAll()))
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the output of both examples should be the same. Regarding the test, you should call `done()` **after** the `expect`. If that doesn't fix it, please update the question with the error you're getting.

Comment: can u share the code for `updateConfirmation` for both version

Comment: @FanCheung I added some more context hope that helps

Comment: @akotech the error is that the test times out after 5 seconds.  It should complete in less than a second and does so if I just do something like `await cr.search().where('symbol').equals(symbol).returnAll()`

Comment: You can probably remove this block just to simplify your code to get to the bottom of the issue first.
` concatAll(),
    combineLatestWith(confirmationRepository$),
    concatMap(async ([conf, confRepo]) => {
      conf.value = !!newData.value
      await confRepo.save(conf)
      return conf
    })`

Answer (score 1):

`concat` only executes each observable passed in and returns each of them sequentially, and it does not mutate anything in between nor does it provide any other means to add conditional checks.

I can see your example using `find` that kinda hack the way through, as it completes the stream when the given condition is met, but it is probably not as semantic or natural as the `switchMap` version

Comment: You concat description is pretty accurate but the two examples you are providing aren't equivalent. The first one would only emit once but the second would emit twice.

Comment: oh yes you are right, forgot to check the `find` behaviour